# intent not working i cant start another activity

Tags: android

complete newbie here .. im creating my first android quiz game. 
i would like to start another activity if button is clicked. (from mainactivity to quizactivity)
i used intent for this but when i try to run it on device and i click on the button, the game crashes . a little help please

here is my main activity

```
package com.example.clicktothink;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);  
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    }
}
```

and here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clicktothink"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.clicktothink.QuizActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.clicktothink.MainActivity"  >     

            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.clicktothink.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.clicktothink.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: is play_bnt declared inside activity_main.xml?

Comment: yes play_btn is declared in activity_main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
please check your mainfest and change that to this .

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.clicktothink"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="16"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



            <activity
                android:name="com.example.clicktothink.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >

                <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
          <activity android:name="com.example.clicktothink.QuizActivity"/>


        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);  

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: hi .. i run the app on actual device not the emulator . tried this not working

Comment: if u get error , post those stack trace  so that we can lead u.

Comment: i get this Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "android:parentActivityName".

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);  
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
```

change to this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);  

        startActivity(intent);
```